# Executing query in client

Tags: mysql, toad

I am using Toad data point to connect to a MySQL database, If I cancel the query in the client (if it's taking long to execute) will MySQL still be running the query?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your database engine mostly and on what Toad actually does. If it sends a `KILL` to query, on `MySIAM` it will actually kill the query mid-way, if you use `InnoDB` it will rollback the transaction, which normally would take about the same time it took to get to the point where you decided to abort the process.